# Cocoa (Touch) for Swing Developers #1: Where Are the Layouts?

Tags: java, iphone, cocoa, cocoa-touch, swing

My iPhone SDK and Objective-C learning is moving ahead quickly, thanks to several great books and online help (including [this one](http://www.iphoneexamples.com/)). But I do have some basic questions due to what I already know that will be answered eventually, but I'd rather get a heads-up now if possible :)

- Are there equivalents for LayoutManagers in Cocoa Touch? Are they used, or is absolute positioning used instead? I have seen some of the layout stuff in IB, but I'm not sure what to look at in code.
- Aside from using the IB, are UIControls added directly to UIView instances using the `addSubview` (like `add` in Swing)?

These are just two concrete questions that I've thought of just now, but I would love to see any translation of Swing concepts to Cocoa Touch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to code up an app like it's a website, [Three20](http://github.com/facebook/three20) is the place to start.   The framework provides a URL-based navigator component roughly equivalent to a front controller called TTNavigator.

To directly answer your question about LayoutManager, there is a point where just about everything devolves into creative use of [UITableView](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html).  It's so customizable and flexible that you can do just about anything.  When that breaks down, it's parent [UIScrollView](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html) is usually a good place to start because it has all the acceleration / bouncing baked-in.

The second question is yes.  [UIViews](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html) are added to UIViews using `- (void)addSubview:(UIView *)view`.  To remove them, use `- (void)removeFromSuperview` from the child view.

Comment: Second and third paragraphs are interesting... why the reference to "code up an app like it's a website?" Just curious, thanks.

Comment: sorry, I probably could have worded that better, I just meant that the navigator makes it more like a centralized action listener

Comment: Ok, so about this creative use of the UITableView: isn't that just one column of things in the iPhone version? My question is if I have, for instance, two rows of controls, do I need to code their positioning myself?

Comment: not necessarily, you can create a customized `UITableViewCell` in IB with your designed layout, then load it with `NSBundle` lazily

Comment: Okay, I'm going to consider all this and then vote you up/mark you best answer when I actually know what we're talking about :).... thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. Sadly not, as a result laying out views manually is a real pain. It took me 5 hours to layout a single view just a few days ago. I've considered building aomething like this and releasing it to the masses.
2. Yes, you are completely right.